# overload Array parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, prototype

i'm Python'ist and i hate ugly js

here is solution to make it usable for me

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

var array_len_plugin = {
    install()
    {
        Array.prototype.len = function () { return this.length }
    }
}


var app = createApp( App )
app.use( array_len_plugin )
app.mount( '#app' )
```

but it's obviously work not as default one

```js
Array.prototype.len = Array.prototype.length
```

how to make this  work?

Comment: What have you tried? `length` is not even a function, and you are expecting it to behave as one?

Comment: @YomT. what i have tried you can see in first `code` section. `is not even a function` - i know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
Object.defineProperty( Array.prototype, "len", { get() { return this.length } } )
```